# Bean doesn't take the value

Tags: jsf

I have the following issue.

Here is the JSF template client:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{booking.actividad}"
                                  layout="pageDirection">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{actividadesClientBean.actividadesByFechaMayor}"
                                   var="m"
                                   itemValue="#{m.id}"
                                   itemLabel="#{m.nombre}"/>
 </h:selectOneRadio>
```

The `value` tag on  `h:selectIneRadio` is supposed to save the `selectedItem` in `actividad String` variable on the booking `Bean`. But when selected, nothing happens. It saves `null`... The Items are correctly rendered, and all what has to do with the UI is correct. I've been looking for 
the error four hours and nothing. Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Bean code:

```
@Named
@FlowScoped("booking")
public class Booking implements Serializable {


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    private double precioC = new Double(0);
    private String tarjeta = "";
    private String actividad;

    public String getActividad() {
        return actividad;
    }

    public void setActividad(String actividad) {
        this.actividad = actividad;
    }
    .......
    .......
    More code
```

It's the first time I work with a `faces-flow`. It might be something related with it. But I'm not quite sure. Here is my flow-chart:

```
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <flow-definition id="booking">
        <flow-return id="goHome">
            <from-outcome>/users/privatepage</from-outcome>
        </flow-return>
    </flow-definition>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: Can you post all the significant part of your page, to recreate a 
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: How does your action and save button look like? If you have problems with flow scope, try it with session or ViewScope to check if that’s your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Comment: the problem was that the h:rm tags were missing

Comment: @ignacioaranguren - I hope the solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61974822/error-writing-java-util-date-into-json-file) worked for you. Do not forget to accept the answer so that future visitors can also use the solution confidently. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.